# How can I set the default value of a new table column during a Code-First Migrations?

Tags: sql, .net, ef-code-first, migration

I'm a bit new to code first migrations and it's giving me a headache...

Basically, I'm trying to create a new table of values ('Breeds' in my example). I want to add a column in another table 'Dogs' which holds a BreedId, cannot be null and has a default value.

After a lot of faff, I've ended up with the code below. (It didn't like the adding the foreign key so I had to comment that bit out).

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.Breeds",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);


Sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Breeds] ON");
Sql("INSERT into [dbo].[Breeds] ([Id], [Name]) VALUES ('1', 'Long Hair')");
Sql("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Breeds] OFF");

AddColumn("dbo.Dogs", "BreedId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: '1'));
//AddForeignKey("dbo.Dogs", "BreedId", "dbo.Breeds", "Id");
CreateIndex("dbo.Dogs", "BreedId");
```

But after running Update-Database, the result is:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Dogs] ADD [BreedId] [int] NOT NULL DEFAULT 49
CREATE INDEX [IX_BreedId] ON [dbo].[Dogs]([BreedId])
```

As you can see the default value has become '49' instead of '1'and I have no idea why.
Can anyone see where I'm going wrong, or is there an easier way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something weird is happening when it is casting the '1' into an integer 1, which it automatically does? Have you tried using the integer 1 instead of '1' and seen if it makes a difference?

Comment: Ah yes - that's it! Removed the quotes and it was fine (must've been a long day...). Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Posting answer thanks to Scotch, removed the quotes then the default value is set correctly.
Like this:

AddColumn("dbo.Dogs", "BreedId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 1));